# How can I make a card deck with fixed-width cards?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to make a responsive [card deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks) using Bootstrap 4 [fixed-width cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#using-custom-css). Here I have posted the code below, but it's not responsive. Why?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-deck">
<div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6" style="max-width: 12rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title 1</h4>
        <p>Small text here</p>
        <small class="text-muted">3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6" style="max-width: 12rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title 2</h4>
        <p>Small text here</p>
        <small class="text-muted">3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6" style="max-width: 12rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title 3</h4>
        <p>Small text here</p>
        <small class="text-muted">3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6" style="max-width: 12rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title 4</h4>
        <p>Small text here</p>
        <small class="text-muted">3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not responsive as not breaking one by one, when decreasing the view port

Answer (score 37):

For a Bootstrap 4 card deck with *fixed-width* cards, do this:

Put each card into a column with the classes `col-auto mb-3` (auto-width column + margin-bottom with three units).

To center them, add the `justify-content-center` class to the row.

Here's a working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that cards will have different heights.

Comment: @ethmz This can be fixed by adding the class `h-100` to the card. Great answer, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

In [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-layout) it is mentioned, **these layout options are not yet responsive**. So I have found a simple solution. Change the parent `<div class="card-deck">...</div>` to `<div class="row">...</div>`.

Answer (score 3):

Deck makes cards equal height.

Adding a row-deleting deck was correct. Adding col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 will give a four-cards desktop, etc. down to one on a phone.

Set the height using the height of the largest number so an "OK" looks straight.